# How to configure gvim to blink when search crosses EOF

Tags: vim

I'm using wrapscan switch, to enable searching to cross EOF, and start from the beginning of file, BUT I'd like to get an indication when the EOF crossing occurs. I know, there is a message at the bottom of the window "search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP", but it is not visual enough.

Is it possible to configure gvim to blink (visual bell) on EOF crossing by the search?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no hook into the search wrapping, so you'd have to at least override the `n` and `N` commands (and potentially most of the search commands if you want to be fully consistent).

Built-in is only the capability to change the highlighting of the message, either by switching *colorschemes*, or by directly manipulating the `WarningMsg` highlight group (after loading the colorscheme):

```
:highlight WarningMsg term=standout cterm=reverse ctermfg=5 ctermbg=15 gui=reverse guifg=Magenta guibg=White
```

Enabling absolute numbering (`:set number`) may also help alerting you to the fact that the cursor has jumped across EOF; the scroll bar position is indeed easy to overlook.

In general, Vim is a power tool that requires careful typing and watching. It pays (in editing efficiency) if you teach yourself to be attentive!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I took it. I didn't know there is something you can't tweak in VI (-: